# Popup based on user account status

Tags: javascript, html, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I want to create a popup which is easy, but here's thing, I want to hide it if you become a paid member, and I want it to appear again if you don't subscribe the next month, I am using the paypal button html code and not the ipn, the paypal button is in the account section of the site, well if you want I can put it in the pop-up and i can use the ipn if i have to, instead of the html code just want someone to guide me on how it's done

Comment: where is this data stored? Do you have a back end or is this just JS and HTML?

Comment: "simple JavaScript question" is a bad title. I edited it to have some meaning.

Comment: @DustinDavis no it could be done by js and html sir, don't worry about the back-end, if you want me to use ipn instead of the paypal standard html code then we have to work with the DB, but in my model i put the paypal button in the account section so that you can sign up for free and go to your account and pay and hide the popup, you see this way i made the process simple, because this way i don't need the ipn, or so i think :D

Comment: @epascarello you are free to edit the question any way you want sir as long as i get the answer I'm looking for lol :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need some sort of user authentication to see if someone has purchased your product or not. This should be handled with a server-side language (PHP, Ruby, etc.) and you can change the layout of your page based on whether the user has authenticated or not.

If you don't have any server-side code, you could use cookies that are saved when you receive a successful callback from PayPal, but that isn't going to be very reliable because they won't be found if the user changes browsers or computers.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use a back-end then use cookies. If they have correct values stored in the cookie, use javascript to hide or change the elemts on the page